# For $\varphi$ in the Schwartz space, why is $ \left[(y, \xi) \mapsto e^{i \xi \cdot x} e^{-i \xi \cdot y} \varphi(y)\right] $ is not integrable

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

There is a technical detail I am trying to understand in the proof that the Fourier transform is a bijection on the Schwartz space.

Theorem. $\mathcal{F} \in \mathcal{L}\left(\mathcal{S}\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right), \mathcal{S}\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)\right)$ is bijective, and for $\varphi \in \mathcal{S}\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)$ we have the inversion formula
$$
\left(\mathcal{F}^{-1} \varphi\right)(x)=(2 \pi)^{-n / 2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{i \xi \cdot x} \varphi(\xi) \mathrm{d} \xi=\hat{\varphi}(-x), \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^n .
$$
PROOF. Fix $\varphi \in \mathcal{S}\left(\mathbb{R}^n\right)$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$. I et us first motivate the subsequent computations and emphasize, that, since
$$
\left[(y, \xi) \mapsto e^{i \xi \cdot x} e^{-i \xi \cdot y} \varphi(y)\right] \notin L_1\left(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n\right),
$$
we cannot apply Fubini's theorem directly to interchange the integration on the right-hand side of
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{i \xi \cdot x} \hat{\varphi}(\xi) \mathrm{d} \xi=(2 \pi)^{-n / 2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} e^{i \xi \cdot x} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \varphi(y) e^{-i \xi \cdot y} \mathrm{~d} y \mathrm{~d} \xi .
$$

I am trying to understand why the statement:

$
\left[(y, \xi) \mapsto e^{i \xi \cdot x} e^{-i \xi \cdot y} \varphi(y)\right] \notin L_1\left(\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n\right),
$

is true, that $
\left[(y, \xi) \mapsto e^{i \xi \cdot x} e^{-i \xi \cdot y} \varphi(y)\right]$ is not integrable.

Comment: $|e^{-i\xi x}e^{-i\xi y}\phi(y)|=|\phi(y)|\not\in L_1(\mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be integrable in $L^1(\Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R^n)$, you need a function that decays in both the $y$ and $\xi$ variables, but
$$
|e^{i\xi\cdot x}\,e^{-i\xi\cdot y}\,\varphi(y)| = |\varphi(y)|
$$
is a constant function of the variable $\xi$, that is for any $y$, the function $\xi\mapsto |\varphi(y)|$ is constant, and so certainly not integrable. More precisely, if you assume by contradiction that $(y,\xi)\mapsto |\varphi(y)|$ is integrable in $L^1(\Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R^n)$, then you get from the Fubini theorem
$$
\int_{\Bbb R^n\times \Bbb R^n} |\varphi(y)|\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm d \xi = \int_{\Bbb R^n} |\varphi(y)|\left(\int_{\Bbb R^n} 1\,\mathrm d \xi\right)\mathrm d y = \infty
$$
since $\int_{\Bbb R^n} 1\,\mathrm d \xi = \infty$, and this contradicts the fact that you assumed $(y,\xi)\mapsto |\varphi(y)|$ to be integrable.

Comment: That was very clear. Thank you :)

Comment: I would not say ”… decays in both …”, since there are unbounded integrable functions.

Comment: Hmm, of course this was not a precise statement but more an heuristic comment. If you prefer, just define "$f$ decays" as "$\int_R^\infty |f|$ converges to $0$ when $R\to\infty$" ;)